# Issue with Featured Image auto-selection in Gmail Grid View

Tags: google-schemas

The new Gmail Grid view displays selected images within emails in a grid like page. I've found a case where Gmail's image auto selection routine may get into a state that results in no image displayed in the Grid View even though there are ample image candidates in the email.

I believe this is caused by a conflict between the routine that selects the image and the routine that processes the image.

- When using the Offer schema markup (bypassing the auto selection process), Gmail allows me to use images as small as 233x161 - this shows that the image processor's minimum is 233x161.
- For emails without Offer schema, Gmail selects an image within an email as small as 100x100 by scanning through the HTML image width and height attributes.
- If an image that falls between 100x100 and 233x161 is selected, it is never rendered, causing an email that may have other larger images in the email to be displayed without a featured image in Grid View.

Here's how I came to this conclusion.

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/flwHy/) is the code I'm referring to:

```
<html><body>

  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <table width="560" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_header_01_01.gif" alt="American Eagle Outfitters" width="154" height="74" border="0"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="560" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo12?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_header_02_01.gif" alt="Men" width="58" height="43" border="0"></a></td>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo13?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_header_02_02.gif" alt="Women" width="91" height="43" border="0"></a></td>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo7a?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_header_02_03.gif" alt="Aerie" width="78" height="43" border="0"></a></td>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo11?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_header_02_04.gif" alt="Shoes" width="83" height="43" border="0"></a></td>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo10?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_header_02_05.gif" width="120" height="43" alt="Clearance" border="0"></a></td>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo8a?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_header_02_06.gif" width="130" height="43" alt="AEO Factory" border="0"></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <table width="560" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo9b?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://placehold.it/560x117" alt="Just Because It's April 1st Doesn't Mean It's April Fools..." width="560" height="117" border="0"></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        BANNER 1 560x117 (above)<BR><BR>

        <table width="560" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="http://e.ae.com/a/hBTOriFB7uylYB85J-eNut-HqBq/aeo9c?AAP_FLAG=N&CUSTOMER_NBR=1317324495393" target="_blank"><img style="display:block;" src="http://f.e.ae.com/i/35/2075863384/AE_Email_140326_3_body_01.gif" alt="Est. 2014 | American Beagle Outfitters" width="560" height="209" border="0"></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <BR>BANNER 2 560x209 (above)<BR><BR>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body></html>
```

This email contains two "main images":

- 560x117
- 560x209

If you sent this email to yourself, there will be no Featured Image.

However, if you swapped the image referenced in 560x117 with an image that is taller than 161 pixels ie. 560x162 then the 560x162 image will be featured in the Grid View.

This leads me to believe that the following is happening:

- The image selection routine selected the 560x117 image because it "passed" its minimum size (100x100).
- Then it sent it to the image processor.
- In the first scenario, the processor retrieved the image and realized its smaller than its minimum dimension (233x161) and rejected it and no image is shown in Grid View.
- In the second scenario, when the image is retrieved, although the HTML width and  height attributes says its 560x117, the image processor retrieves the image and detects the real image dimension as 560x162. Since this is above its minimum, the image is processed and displayed in the Grid View.

I added the second image to show that if you merely removed the first image (in a separate test), the 560x209 image will be featured - which lead me to believe the first image is causing a problem since no image is featured at all originally.

Possible resolution:

- Change the image auto-selection routine to only select images that are 233x161 or larger

Comment: @andrew-barber I am not asking a question. I'm reporting a possible bug as Google has specified StackOverflow to be used as the forum for Schema related discussion. Perhaps this is the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed report, the engineers are investigating the issue. Obviously, the recommendation is to use microdata to control the experience and not rely on the internal image selection logic that can change at any time.

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino definitely microdata is the way to go! Just thought if this was some edge case bug that it might help senders who are not aware of microdata not to have their emails look ugly :)